# WD TV Live: Does it play downloading file?

Tags: wdtv

I have a question regarding new WD TV Live. Does it play a video file while the file is being downloaded over network?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think yes, because you can to connect to Internet sites like YouTube, Flickr, Live365 or stream content from your home network.